# Django File object and S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, zip, python-django-storages

So I have added s3 support to one of my Django projects. (storages and boto3)
I have a model that has a file field with zip-archive with images in it.

At some point I need to access this zip-archive and parse it to create instances of another model with those images from archive. It looks something like this:

- I access archive data with `zipfile`
- Get image from it
- Put this image to django File object
- Add this file object to model field
- Save model

I works perfectly fine without s3, however with it I get `UnsupportedOperation: seek` error.
My guess is that boto3/storages does not support uploading files to s3 from memory files. Is it the case? If so, how to fix id/ avoid this in this kind of situation?

Comment: Here when you say Django File like object, make sure the object supports basic file operations like read(), write(), seek(), etc